# Classic question deleted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

Why was this "classic" Stack Overflow question deleted?

[What's your biggest fear as a programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347190/whats-your-biggest-fear-as-a-programmer/)

I think it was a good example of mood and spirit of Stack Exchange people, and closing would have been enough.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it should be allowed to stay?

Comment: It's hardly an example of a useful question, even if non-constructive / off-topic today.

Comment: It's been deleted for over 2.5 years. Not the classic you think it is, methinks.

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com/export?service=stackoverflow&question=3347190&printer=false&linktohome=true Grab it, host it somewhere if you think it's useful.

Comment: OK, I've followed a link talking about the question and it just surprise me that it was deleted

Comment: Stack Overflow focus on the professional side, not fun side, of programming.

Comment: Meta, on the other hand...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd perhaps a move to programmers and closing the question would have been better

Comment: @HernánEche I might be mistaken, but I think this is (by now) equally unsuitable for the Programmers SE.

Comment: Don't think that programmers site is place for fun as well. Stack Exchange sites in general focus on being professional, each in its own niche/field of expertise. For fun you have more than enough other sites.

Comment: @HernánEche - It most certainly is not suitable for Programmers. Programmers is even more strict than [SO] - just look at their FAQ (this since they decided they really don't want to be the dumping ground of everything [SO] doesn't want).

Comment: @Bart I think that was a good example of some human side of programming, and a very unlinke topic, then interesting one for being totally deleted.

Comment: @HernánEche There are tons of programming related questions and interesting topics I would love to read or discuss. But these sites have a very narrow scope, for good reasons, and such questions simply don't fit here. The data is still around however, so you're free to host it if you want to preserve it.

Comment: @Bart I understand, really, but the community didn't start talking "narrow", this community grew by gaining confidence, by not being deleted for a scope, this was tolerant, that question itself prove it, it was upvoted, and I even agree is not welcome today, but why to despise the history?

Comment: Because it is so significantly off-topic and (imo) of so little real value to the site, that keeping it around would only serve to confuse. Some questions are kept because they have a high value, even when they are not a good fit. They might receive a historical lock. In my opinion, this particular question would not deserve that treatment.

Comment: @Bart It's ok, there is people outside programming that found it useful, but of course they could still browse it from stackprinter or web.archive.org, thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

> and closing would have been enough.

Why closing if it has **no chances** to **ever** be reopened ?

This question does't fit at all in the Q/A standards of Stack Overlfow.
 
This question is a *give me your opinion* question and such questions do not have their places on Stack Overflow.

I recommand you refer to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to get get a better understanding of which questions should stay on this site.

Comment: I am asking you to argue about it, this is meta, and it's supposed here we can talk about stackoverflow as something able to change, as it was changing over the years, so I've ask for personal views, to understand perhaps deeply why we exclude (even in the site and the faq, etc) "human" opinion. If I ask here is because I want to read some interesting opinion about it, not an algorithm that automatically checks faq rules

Comment: @HernánEche The comment section is used for arguing about your point. The many downvotes you collected reflects the community's opinion about your subject. Now I explain why this will never happen. That's how it works. Stack Overflow is strict when it comes to its Q/A format and I don't see that ever changing.